# CodeIgniter: Accessing Language Files from Config?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In one of my config files, I want to access language line items. How can I do that? I tried getting an instance of CI and accessing it that way (e.g. `$CI->lang->line('foo')`), but that didn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: Can you please provide code so people get better understanding of your problem? other wise people will keep guessing about different scenario. e.g. are you adding this line in system default config file or user created config file?

Comment: Does it matter if it's a system default config or created config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `pre_controller` hook that will set config item each request.

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->lang->load('filename');
$CI->config->set_item('item_name', $CI->lang->line('language_key'));
```

Or something like that.